# angular ng-repeat checkbox from resource and set checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have resource in my controller and populate checkboxes with ng-repeat
next thing i know in controller which are to be checked

code will looks like..

```
$scope.data = resource.query();

var arr_to_be_checked = [1,3,5];
```

in other controller i use this..

```
$scope.data = [ { Type: 1, checked: true, Title: 'Item A'},
                { Type: 2, checked: false, Title: 'Item B'}];
```

and its working fine but i need apply this on resource and ng-repeat because i need more flexible

i find any soulution but without point. Pls can you help me anyone?

**My question is: How i can "override" objects in resource with 'checked:true' or set any checkbox as checked.**

Thank you so much for help or any idea
Have a nice day

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in data">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="item.checked"> {{item.Title}}
  </li>
</ul>
<button ng-click="checkItems()">Do</button>
```

.

```
$scope.checkItems = function () {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < arr_to_be_checked.length; i++) {
    data[arr_to_be_checked[i]].checked = true;
  } 
};
```

PS: Please be really consistent on your naming conventions, javascript uses a `camelCase` naming convention, no underscores. Only constructor functions are named `PascalCase`

Related API Documentation:
[ng-click](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClick)
[ng-checked](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngChecked)

Comment: ty for help, but my problem is so i cant fill checked property automatic in controller. I know how i can make this with button but i need other interactions. I need set checked from my array on load page. User clicked on checkbox and page is refresh but i know after that wich is checked but after refresh i have all unchecked. I need change property on load. Understand me or my english is stupid?

Comment: If you want that to be automatic, the best way to do so is to watch your 'data' property and when it changes, set the item's as checked.

Comment: Watching is good idea but its dont know which checkbox may be checked. Its working fine but i dont know how to say "yes this checkbox may be checked". You can create easy example on jsfiddle? thx fastereload

Answer (score 7):

Another solution:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <label ng-repeat="(color,enabled) in colors">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="colors[color]" /> {{color}} 
  </label>
  <p>colors: {{colors}}</p>

<script>
  var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
      $scope.colors = {Blue: true, Orange: true};
  });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/U4VD61?p=preview

Comment: good thank for your response. But my point was i had normal array not as object. With objects work fine but i needed set checked boxes from normal array. If you'll have any soulution iam listening. Iam glad for response. ty

Comment: Easy: just `$scope.$watch(colors)` the object and update another key to be an array :) Keep it simple

Comment: This solution does not keep the order

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**
i look at solution from **fastreload** and modified like this..

```
var arr_checked_items = [1,2,5] // this checkboxes will be set as checked


<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in data">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="checkItem(item.id)"> {{item.Title}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

.

```
$scope.checkItem = function (id) {
   var checked = false;
   for(var i=0; i<= arr_to_be_checked.length; i++) {
      if(id == arr_to_be_checked[i]) {
         checked = true;
      }
    }
    return checked;
};
```

ITS WORKING PERFECT !!! on load without any clicking buttons

Comment: -point ok .. so iam waiting for better solution here, because i was ask before. Iam very sad if iam ask for help and anyone come here and give me -1 without word... i never say its best solution but working and i need working and not waiting for -points...

Comment: Maybe its because you asked a question, got help from @fastreload, and then rewote your answer using his code, without giving him any upvotes. Thats not how it works round here.

Comment: ok ... iam new here and i wanted to give him upvote ofc, but he give me idea not correct answer. I forgot him give upvote. Sorry